# Download BIM360 Docs file using Javascript

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to download BIM360 docs files using javascript. I am able to get file response from BIM360 but unable to save file with proper content. Here is my JS code -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var anchor = $('.vcard-hyperlink');
    $.ajax({
        url: <file downloaded URL>,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + <accessToken>
        },
        beforeSend: function (jqxhr) {

        },
        success: function (data) {
            // create a blob url representing the data
            var blob = new Blob([data]);
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            // attach blob url to anchor element with download attribute
            var anchor = document.createElement('a');
            anchor.setAttribute('href', url);
            anchor.setAttribute('download', "test.docx");
            anchor.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        },
        error: function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a FYI that you should NOT use such approach, all communication with Forge should be performed server-side and the data should be exposed to your client page through controlled custom endpoints exposed by your own server app... Exposing a token to the client app would make your data vulnerable, it should be considered as a security issue. Give me the url of your app and I will harvest all the design data from your A360 account (potentially delete your files as well, depending which scope you used for that token) :) Use one of the server-side SDK  that we made available to you

Comment: Thanks @Philippe, I am using data:read scope and don't want stream the data from my server due to that I am using JS download approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download files from BIM360 service, I used a custom [Ajax transports](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxtransport/) of the jQuery to creates new XMLHttpRequest and passes all the received data back to the jQuery, see [here](http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/) for the detail of the Ajax transports with jQuery.

```
/**
 *
 * jquery.binarytransport.js
 *
 * @description. jQuery ajax transport for making binary data type requests.
 * @version 1.0 
 * @author Henry Algus <henryalgus@gmail.com>
 *
 */
// use this transport for "binary" data type
$.ajaxTransport("+binary", function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    // check for conditions and support for blob / arraybuffer response type
    if (window.FormData && ((options.dataType && (options.dataType == 'binary')) || (options.data && ((window.ArrayBuffer && options.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) || (window.Blob && options.data instanceof Blob))))) {
        return {
            // create new XMLHttpRequest
            send: function(headers, callback) {
                // setup all variables
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                    url = options.url,
                    type = options.type,
                    async = options.async || true,
                    // blob or arraybuffer. Default is blob
                    dataType = options.responseType || "blob",
                    data = options.data || null,
                    username = options.username || null,
                    password = options.password || null;

                xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
                    var data = {};
                    data[options.dataType] = xhr.response;
                    // make callback and send data
                    callback(xhr.status, xhr.statusText, data, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
                });

                xhr.open(type, url, async, username, password);

                // setup custom headers
                for (var i in headers) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader(i, headers[i]);
                }

                xhr.responseType = dataType;
                xhr.send(data);
            },
            abort: function() {
                jqXHR.abort();
            }
        };
    }
});
```

The following code snippet is the code I used for downloading a file from BIM360 bucket via Forge Data Management API. With the above custom Ajax transports and `dataType: 'binary'`, the API response will be processed as a blob. Afterward, we just need to create a blob URL and a temporary HTML link to open the blob URL for saving the downloaded file.

To obtain the actual file storage URL, you have to call API [GET Item Versions](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-versions-GET/), and the download link is the value of the `storage.meta.link.href` attribute of each item version data in the API response.

```
$(function() {

  $('a#download').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const filename = '2f536896-88c8-4dee-b0c1-cdeee231a028.zip';

    const settings = {
      crossDomain: true,
      url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/' + filename,
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'binary',
      processData: false,
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN',
        Content-Type: 'application/octet-stream'
      }
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (blob, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(blob );
        console.log(textStatus);

      if( navigator.msSaveBlob )
        return navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);

      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.style = 'display: none';
      document.body.appendChild(a);

      a.href = url;
      a.download = filename;
      a.click();
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    });
  });
})
```

Hope it helps.